# How do I modify this schematic to be input/output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, signal, circuit-design

J2 and J3 are audio jacks. The purpose of having 2 is because I want to be able to hear the original audio signal through an external speaker. I'm worried that this circuit configuration may introduce noise from the external speaker. If I add diodes, idk if it will disrupt the audio signal.

Do you guys have any suggestions?
You guys are awesome, thx in advance!

[image: Circuitry Schematic]

Comment: First I would try with just two more resistors and connect to the common capacitor junction.  This will decrease the effect of any output on the other by twice the resistor attenuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is **high impedance**, in other words, the current coming from J3 doesn't leak into J2. But you want the voltage to be *copied*. That asks for an operational amplifier in follower (aka buffer) mode.

I copied your schematic so you would feel most familiar with it.

[image]

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Ac%20480%20224%20544%20224%200%200.00001%200%0AO%20480%20224%20432%20224%200%0Aw%20544%20224%20544%20192%200%0Aw%20544%20224%20544%20256%200%0Ar%20544%20192%20656%20192%200%201000%0Ar%20544%20256%20656%20256%200%201000%0Aw%20720%20192%20800%20192%200%0Aw%20800%20192%20816%20208%200%0Aw%20816%20208%20832%20192%200%0Aw%20736%20256%20800%20256%200%0Aw%20800%20256%20816%20240%200%0Aw%20816%20240%20832%20256%200%0Aw%20736%20272%20848%20272%200%0Aw%20848%20272%20848%20208%200%0Aw%20720%20192%20656%20192%200%0Aw%20736%20256%20656%20256%200%0Aw%20736%20272%20640%20272%200%0Ag%20640%20272%20640%20320%200%0Aw%20848%20512%20848%20448%200%0Aw%20736%20512%20848%20512%200%0Aw%20816%20480%20832%20496%200%0Aw%20800%20496%20816%20480%200%0Aw%20736%20496%20800%20496%200%0Aw%20816%20448%20832%20432%200%0Aw%20800%20432%20816%20448%200%0Aw%20736%20432%20800%20432%200%0Ag%20640%20512%20640%20528%200%0Aw%20736%20512%20640%20512%200%0Aa%20736%20320%20736%20416%200%2015%20-15%201000000%200%200%0Aa%20672%20384%20672%20480%200%2015%20-15%201000000%200%200%0Aw%20688%20384%20704%20384%200%0Aw%20704%20384%20704%20480%200%0Aw%20704%20480%20672%20480%200%0Aw%20736%20416%20768%20416%200%0Aw%20768%20416%20768%20320%200%0Aw%20768%20320%20752%20320%200%0Aw%20720%20320%20720%20192%200%0Aw%20736%20416%20736%20432%200%0Aw%20672%20480%20672%20496%200%0Aw%20672%20496%20736%20496%200%0Aw%20656%20256%20656%20384%200%0Ax%20805%20418%20827%20421%204%2024%20J2%0Ax%20801%20169%20823%20172%204%2024%20J3%0Ax%20590%20167%20622%20170%204%2024%20R5%0Ax%20582%20295%20614%20298%204%2024%20R7%0Ax%20494%20267%20526%20270%204%2024%20C3%0A) if you want to.. I don't know, mess around.

**Nearly any op-amp will do the job.** If you want to be sure that it works for you, then make sure that the bandwidth of the op-amp is at least 100kHz for **some margin** (audible max frequency is usually around 22kHz). I'm not 100% sure if the voltage will be flying all over the place, but if you are aware that it does, then you might consider using a rail-to-rail to make sure that the op-amp *copies* the voltage from J3 for *all* voltages. ([LM358](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) for an example can output 0 to VDD-1.5V, so if you feed an LM358 with 5V then its output will only be from 0V to 3.5V)

Keep in mind that whatever op-amp you use to do this, its output will always be within what you're feeding the op-amp with. So if you feed the op-amp with -9V and 9V then its output will be able to go near -9V and near 9V. In other words, if your audio is centered around 0V, aka GND, then you shouldn't use GND as your negative voltage supply for the op-amp, because then the op-amp won't be able to make the negative voltages that the audio is making. It will be clipping the audio and it will sound nasty.

My final answer/advice is this: Follow your own schematic, you **will** lose some sound and introduce some noise, you might not hear the difference and everything will be nice and dandy. Or you will hear that the sound is about half because J3 is trying to drive two systems. Either way, if it doesn't work, then I'd do my schematic and make sure that the op-amp can output all the voltages you feed it. So if the voltage will dip down to -3V, then I'd make sure to feed the op-amp with at least -3V so it can make that voltage at its output. So this answer *greatly* depends on what your inputs voltage actually is like.

Comment: Super awesome, thanks for the help! (I'm a newbie to audio circuitry.) I'd rather not have rail to rail because I dont want to introduce a negative supply to my circuit, but the contents of my audio signal will be music which should be below 22 kHz. Again, thanks so much - I'll test out the LM358

Comment: rail-to-rail means that the output can go from the minimum voltage you're feeding the op-amp with to the maximum voltage you're feeding the op-amp with. It has nothing to do with negative voltages.

Comment: Ah that's right, thx. Fixed my understanding on that too. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Edit circuit to cater for single supply design. Basically just tap the line signal and connect to a headphone amp.
[image]

The impedance of this circuit is more than 10k ohm so it's unlikely to interfere your signal to the speaker. Also do note I don't add resistor is series as it will reduce the gain of your speakers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faM2hu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For line signal, the signal can goes up to 2V and not adjustable. Potentiameter R3 is for you to reduce the volume. To further reduce the gain, increase R3 value. R3 and C7 is for low pass filter, the value I insert is not finalize. You can check it out here. Just filter anything above 40kHz will do.

[image: 1st order low pass filter]